# Odd behavior in passed params with React Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Here's the screen:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'

export default class ContentScreen extends React.Component {    
  render() {
    const { state } = this.props.navigation;
    const { code } = state.params.code
    return(
      <Text>CONTENT GOES HERE: {JSON.stringify(state)} / '{code}'</Text>
    )
  }
}
```

And the navigation invocation:

```
<TouchableOpacity key={k} onPress={() => {navigate("Content", {code: k})}} style={styles.listing}>
```

And here's what's displayed:

```
CONTENT GOES HERE: {"params":{"code":"222"},"key":"id-151010...","routeName":"Content"} / ''
```

Which is really @(#$ weird. The value clearly exists at `state.params.code`, as can be seen by the JSON string, and yet when accessed, it isn't present. `Object.values(state.params)` and `Object.keys(state.params)` give the expected results (`["code"]` and `["222"]`).

So, like, any ideas as to what's going on? Or ideas about how to further investigate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are destructuring one level too deep.

```
const { code } = state.params.code;
```

This is basically looking for this.props.state.params.code.code

Try:

```
Const { code } = state.params;
```

Or:

```
const { navigation: { state: { params: { code } } } } = this.props;
```